# Truffle invalid address

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc, truffle-contract, truffle-config

With Truffle 3.0 when I call one of my contract's function, in console I have this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address

I found  [this](http://www.bullraider.com/ethereum/tutorials/342-understanding-invalid-address-error-in-dapps-or-geth-console) workaround, and in my code I try this with no success.

```
this.web3Provided.eth.defaultAccount=this.web3Provided.eth.coinbase;
```

In [truffle doc](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/develop/advanced/configuration/) they sat I can set a from address in my config, but also this not work. `from: '0x8c384d9f226ea92c99f7aa83340714a6f82a3161'`

I also try with this after I have imported all truffle.config file:

```
TruffleConfig.networks[NODE_ENV].from = this.web3Provided.eth.coinbase;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 13):

Thank's to Truffle Gitter channel I figured out. I have to call defaults function on my truffle-contract's abstraction.

```
MyContract.defaults({from: …})
```

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/truffle-contract

```
buildContracts() {
    let contracts = {};
    let meta;

    this.props.contracts.forEach( _contract => {
      let {contract_name = ''} = _contract;
      meta = contract(_contract);
      meta.setProvider(this.web3Provided.currentProvider);
      meta.defaults({from: this.web3Provided.eth.coinbase});
      contracts[contract_name] = meta;
    });
    return contracts;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post an elaborated answer, like where you have added the line?  I am also getting the same error while calling a contract's function using web3. I am using testrpc. The contract was deployed via truffle.

Comment: This is my build contract function, a simple function that loop my contract list. For each contract I had to set a default with a coinbase.

buildContracts() {
    let contracts = {};
    let meta;

    this.props.contracts.forEach( _contract => {
      let {contract_name = ''} = _contract;
      meta = contract(_contract);
      meta.setProvider(this.web3Provided.currentProvider);
      meta.defaults({from: this.web3Provided.eth.coinbase});
      contracts[contract_name] = meta;
    });
    return contracts;
  }

Comment: Thanks a bunch - adding `contract.default({from: ...})` - fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. Hope my answer helps future readers.

You have to the set the defaultAccount to be used:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

before using **web3** instance.

Also, In my case where I'm using **react-truffle** box, the invalid address can be solved by adding.

```
this.state.web3.eth.defaultAccount = this.state.web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

before doing anything related to **web3**.

> **NOTE :** Changing states in react like this is highly not recommended. Try using `this.setState()` to manipulate the web3 object's child. I haven't thought much about the app that I'm developing so for me if this works, **I'M GOLDEN** :D

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? Why doesn't truffle do this by default?

Comment: I'm not sure why truffle doesn't do this by default, but my guess is `web3.eth.accounts[0];` part which should not be statically defined.

Answer (score 2):

I had an owner withdrawal function in my smart contract that would throw the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address

I eventually realized that either Truffle or MetaMask expects an explicit `from` address.

This was my original function definition:

```
ownerWithdrawal() {
    return this.contractInstance.ownerWithdrawal(); // calls ownerWithdrawal() from Solidity contract
  }
```

Here is my new function definition with `from` address specified.

```
ownerWithdrawal() {
    return this.contractInstance.ownerWithdrawal({from: this.web3accounts[0]});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

using an old version of web3 for an outdated tutorial web3@0.20.6 and Firefox 100.0.1

this was what I added to react to get around the problem

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default account for web3 or adding a from property will fix the error. You can consult the web3.eth documentation here [(web3.eth documentation)](https://This%20default%20address%20is%20used%20as%20the%20default%20%22from%22%20property,%20if%20no%20%22from%22%20property%20is%20specified%20in%20for%20the%20following%20methods:)