# Why doesn't truffle set the defaultAccount by default?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

According to this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12957/truffle-invalid-address/12960), whenever you're trying to interact with the contract's state via `truffle develop`, you have to do this:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

Why isn't this done by default, like with the `migrate` command which deploys the contract from the first address in the generated account list?